# Running CQEngine in distributed environment

Tags: java, distributed-caching

I have an application which the underlying data cache is using CQEngine. It is extremely fast and reliable. However I'm currently looking into creating a cluster of CQEngine that can share the data. Has anyone encounter this?

Answer (score 1):

(Though an old question..)
I haven't worked with CQEngine, but if the particular framework allows you to pick your own collections underneeth the indices it creates maybe a good choice is [Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.com) grid which is designed for distributed environments

Let us know if you manage to merge the two together smoothly

hope it helps